# How to use polymorphic user model with devise authentication on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, polymorphism

I'm developing an application using devise , which has more than one type of user and each type has different data fields . For this, I am trying to use the idea applied here: http://blog.jeffsaracco.com/ruby-on-rails-polymorphic-user-model-with-devise-authentication.

My situation is exactly like this blog. I want to have only a login screen, but having more than one user table ( one for each type ), not to get a table with several empty fields.

The problem is that I tried to implement exactly the same as example and in my case is not working.

My models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :type, :polymorphic => true

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :user, :as => :type
end
```

i'll put just this two models, because the others its the same for a while.

Controllers:

```
class PatientsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    @patient = Patient.new(patient_params)
    @user.type = @patient

    if @patient.save
        @user.save
        redirect_to @patient
    else
        render 'new'
    end
  end
```

My view:

```
<%= form_for @patient, :url => patients_path(@patient), :html => {:method => :post} do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :name, "Nome" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder:"Digite o nome do Paciente", required:"", autofocus: true %>
    <br>

    <%= f.fields_for :user do |u| %>
        <%= u.label :email %><br />
        <%= u.email_field :email %>

        <%= u.label :password %>
        <%= u.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>

        <%= u.label :password_confirmation %><br />
        <%= u.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>

    <% end %>

    <%= f.submit "Ok" %>
<% end %>
```

My migrations:

```
class CreatePatients < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :patients do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
  end
end
```

And the error i'm getting is:

> ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError in PatientsController#create  can't
>   write unknown attribute `type_id`

I'm sorry for this huge post, but I did not want my doubt stay confused because I am researching this for some time and have found many related things , but nothing that would solve the problem.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You don't have a `type_id` attribute in `users` table. Create a migration for `type_id` and do `rake db:migrate`

Comment: Hi @Pavan, thanks very much for your attention, i included this: "t.integer :type_id" on the user migration. Is that correct? If it is, this didn't solve the problem, because now i got this:

ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError in PatientsController#create
can't write unknown attribute `type_type`

PS: This was the only modification.
PS2: What i'm doing, sounds normal to you? Or do you think this is not regular and could be done in another way?

Anyway, thanks a lot!!

Comment: You are using polymorphic associations, so you need to have `type_type` attribute as well in the users table. For more details please refer to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Comment: @Pavan thanks for the guide, Actually, I did not know that. I included this " type_type ", but still keep having another problem: The User is not being saved, the patient is saved without error, but is not stored the User, i tried to put an "@ user.save! " And it returns me : Validation failed: Email can not be blank , password can not be blank
Apparently , the parameters are not being sent . I made no other modification beyond the insertions on the migration of User fields : type_id and Type_type. Sorry for my english buddy.